# Why is MySql select sum a few rows and a lot of rows returned at same speed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have this table with only about 50k data records in my database, and when I query select sum from this table, I found out that select sum 2 records and select sum 5k records, returned at exactly the same speed, I really wonder why is that, shouldn't querying lesser records should be faster ? Anyway here is my query.

```
$this->db->select("SUM(((c.qty_in * c.product_factor) - (c.qty_out * c.product_factor)) as total_qty, b.product_PID, b.product_name, a.product_color");
$this->db->from('data_product_color a');
$this->db->join('data_product b', 'a.product_PID = b.product_PID');
$this->db->join('transaction c', 'a.product_color_PID = c.product_color_PID');
$where = "/* where statement */";
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->group_by('a.product_color_PID');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

So with the code above when I supply the where argument to select 2 records or 100 records or 1k or 5k records, they all returned result at the same time, could anyone explain why is this and how do I make returning fewer records faster ?

Comment: How long does it take to return?

Comment: @scsimon 12 seconds

Comment: `$this->db->join('transaction c', 'a.product_color_PID = b.product_color_PID');` looks like a typo, since your join doesn't include the transaction table

Comment: We'd need to see the execution plans for both to speed it up then.  Feel free to paste those links (google paste the plan) in the original post. I'm not shocked they run at the same speed. 5k rows is trivial. So improvements will improve both queries.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the total records in the table but still, querying lesser records should return faster, when I try the same exact query with SELECT only, lesser records return faster, 100 records return in less than 1 second and 5k records in less than 10 s

Comment: @TiesonT. Oh yeah sorry, will edit it

Comment: MySQL or sql server? You tagged both

Comment: @scsimon MySQL sorry, will remove sql-server tag

Comment: Based on your edit, I'd assume `$this->db->join('data_product b', 'a.product_PID = b.product_PID');` isn't necessary, since you're not referencing data_product in the SELECT statement.

Comment: @TiesonT. I did need data from table b, I just didn't include it in my question, will include the select from table b too then.

Comment: Please add the `explain` output (as scsimon asked). If you do a full table scan (which means your `where`-condition isn't supported by an index), MySQL has to read the whole table and check every row, no matter if it adds the row to the result or not. Also be aware that you cannot `select` columns that are neither used in an aggregate or used in your `group by` (like `b.product_PID`). (MySQL might, depending on settings and version, not complain about it, but will return values of any random row for these 2 columns, and, although they usually are, they don't even have to be from the same row).